# Долгая загрузка данных в List

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

Если в xaml сделать такую структуру, то загрузка `ListView` происходит очень долго(порядка 3х секунд).

```
<Grid Background="White" x:Name="ContentPanelBus" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <ScrollViewer>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
                            <GridView
                                ItemClick="BusesGridView_ItemClick"
                            x:Name="BusesGridView"
                            AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
                            AutomationProperties.Name="Items In Group"
                            IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                            ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.ExitElementContainer="True">

                                <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" MaximumRowsOrColumns="4"/>
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </GridView.ItemsPanel>

                                <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
                                                <TransitionCollection>
                                                    <PopupThemeTransition/>
                                                </TransitionCollection>
                                            </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>

                                            <Border Width="{Binding Path=size}" Height="{Binding Path=size}" Background="White" BorderBrush="{Binding Path=color}" BorderThickness="1" Margin="5,5,5,5">
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=number}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="{Binding Path=color}" FontSize="26" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
                                            </Border>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                            </GridView>
                            <ListView x:Name="RoutesAllBus" Background="White" SelectionChanged="SelectBus">
                                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
                                                <TransitionCollection>
                                                    <PopupThemeTransition></PopupThemeTransition>
                                                </TransitionCollection>
                                            </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>

                                            <StackPanel Background="White" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="65" Margin="10,0,10,0" Width="{Binding Path=screen_size}" >
                                                <Grid Width="50" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                                    <Ellipse Fill="{Binding Path=color}"/>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=number}" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="26"></TextBlock>
                                                </Grid>
                                                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=name}" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,10,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="18" Width="330"></TextBlock>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListView>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Grid>
```

Если таким образом построить структуру то загрузка происходит мгновенно:

```
<Grid Background="White" x:Name="ContentPanelBus" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <ListView x:Name="RoutesAllBus" Background="White" SelectionChanged="SelectBus">
                        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                            </Style>
                        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
                                        <TransitionCollection>
                                            <PopupThemeTransition></PopupThemeTransition>
                                        </TransitionCollection>
                                    </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>

                                    <StackPanel Background="White" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="65" Margin="10,0,10,0" Width="{Binding Path=screen_size}" >
                                        <Grid Width="50" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                            <Ellipse Fill="{Binding Path=color}"/>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=number}" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="26"></TextBlock>
                                        </Grid>
                                        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=name}" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,10,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="18" Width="330"></TextBlock>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </Grid>
```

Но мне необходимо сделать в одном `Grid` 2 внутренних элемента: `ListView` и `GridView`
В чем проблема? Может быть какое-нибудь решение есть попроще?

Вся проблема возникает из-за `StackPanel`.(проверенно методом тыка)

Comment: Если вы приведёте пример, воспроизводящий проблему, возможно, нам будет легче вам помочь. На пустых списках разница в скорости незаметна.

Comment: @VladD Суть не в том что внутри, суть в том что из-за StackPanel загрузка происходит дольше

Comment: [VirtualizingStackPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.aspx) пробовали?

Comment: @ixSci, не пробовали, вообще впервые слышу про это

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, так как не дождался ответов, пришлось немного самому поразмыслить. Из за того что у меня отображается на экране либо лист, либо грид(не 2 одновременно) даннуб проблему можно решить путем установки высоты грида на 0 а высоты листа на *, и наоборот.